# How to check if Celery/Supervisor is running using Python

Tags: python, flask, celery, supervisord

How to write a script in Python that outputs if celery is running on a machine (Ubuntu)?

My use-case. I have a simple python file with some tasks. I'm not using Django or Flask. I use supervisor to run the task queue. For example,

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import Celery, task
app = Celery('tasks')
@app.task()
def add_together(a, b):
    return a + b
```

**Supervisor:**

```
[program:celery_worker]
directory = /var/app/
command=celery -A tasks worker info
```

This all works, I now want to have page which checks if celery/supervisor process is running. i.e. something like this maybe using Flask allowing me to host the page giving a 200 status allowing me to load balance.

For example...

**check_status.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def status_check():

    #check supervisor is running
    if supervisor:
         return render_template('up.html')
    else:
        return render_template('down.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Update 09/2020: Jérôme updated this answer for Celery 4.3 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57628025/1159735

You can run the `celery status` command via code by importing the `celery.bin.celery` package:

```
import celery
import celery.bin.base
import celery.bin.celery
import celery.platforms

app = celery.Celery('tasks', broker='redis://')

status = celery.bin.celery.CeleryCommand.commands['status']()
status.app = status.get_app()

def celery_is_up():
    try:
        status.run()
        return True
    except celery.bin.base.Error as e:
        if e.status == celery.platforms.EX_UNAVAILABLE:
            return False
        raise e

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if celery_is_up():
        print('Celery up!')
    else:
        print('Celery not responding...')
```

Comment: I don't have any upvotes left for today, so I am upvoting this method by a comment.

Comment: I don't think `app = celery.Celery('tasks', broker='redis://')` line is necessary. The `app` variable is not used anywhere else.

Comment: @djromero it's been awhile since I checked how this worked, but IIRC it's needed to instantiate the singleton app in the library internals. It shouldn't be needed if you use celery somewhere else and it creates the celery instance.

Comment: @vgel Nice solution. What about celery beat? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this solution, just one question here, does status.run() return any value, how will you make sure whether it worked or not. Is it based on exception raised?

Answer (score 2):

How about using subprocess, not sure if it is a good idea:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> output = subprocess.check_output('ps aux'.split())
>>> 'supervisord' in output
True
```

Answer (score 2):

you can parse [process state](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#process-states) from `supervisorctl status` output

```
import subprocess

def is_celery_worker_running():
    ctl_output = subprocess.check_output('supervisorctl status celery_worker'.split()).strip()
    if ctl_output == 'unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock no such file':
        # supervisord not running
        return False
    elif ctl_output == 'No such process celery_worker':
        return False
    else:
        state = ctl_output.split()[1]
        return state == 'RUNNING'
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [@vgel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33545849/4653485), using Celery 4.3.0.

```
import celery
import celery.bin.base
import celery.bin.control
import celery.platforms

# Importing Celery app from my own application
from my_app.celery import app as celery_app


def celery_running():
    """Test Celery server is available

    Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/33545849
    """
    status = celery.bin.control.status(celery_app)
    try:
        status.run()
        return True
    except celery.bin.base.Error as exc:
        if exc.status == celery.platforms.EX_UNAVAILABLE:
            return False
        raise


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if celery_is_up():
        print('Celery up!')
    else:
        print('Celery not responding...')
```

Comment: The line
`status = celery.bin.control.status(celery_app)`
is giving me an error:
`TypeError: 'Celery' object is not iterable`

Comment: I'm using version 5.0.5 and the docs seem to disappear.
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v5.0.5/reference/celery.bin.control.html

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for version 5.0?

Answer (score 1):

A sparse web user interface comes with supervisor. May be you could use that. It can be enabled in the supervisor config. Key to look for is [inet_http_server]

You could even look at the source code of that piece to get ideas to implement your own.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't applicable for celery, but for anyone that ended up here to see if supervisord is running, check to see if the pidfile defined for supervisord in your `supervisord.conf` configuration file exists.  If so, it's running; if not, it isn't.  The default pidfile is /tmp/supervisord.pid, which is what I used below.

```
import os
import sys

if os.path.isfile("/tmp/supervisord.pid"):
    print "supervisord is running."
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score -2):

In my experience, I'd set a message to track whether it was complete or not so that the queues would be responsible for retrying tasks.